# Get name from category table with two other tables

Tags: mysql, join, where-clause

I am trying to get the category name from categories linkt with a retailer_id and category_id

These are the three tables:

```
1)retailers,
retailer_id

2)retailer_to_category,
retailer_id and
category_id

3)categories,
category_id and
name
```

I want to select the (categories) name.

I tried many options but nothing seems to help.

```
$query = "
SELECT s.name
     , c.retailer_id
     , b.retailer_id
  FROM categories s
  JOIN retailer_to_category b 
    ON s.category_id = b.category_id
  JOIN retailers c 
    ON b.retailer_id = c.retailer_id
";
```

But that only displays the first category name in the database table, whichever retailer I select

Comment: SQL query looks fine - I suggest you test this by itself and then look at whatever it is you are using to process the result of this query (php?)

Comment: $result = smart_mysql_query($query);
  $catrow = mysqli_fetch_array($result);  <?php echo $catrow['name']; ?>